# conditional distribution of random variable given its sum with another random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to figure out the following problem:

> I have two random variables: $X$ with pdf $f_X(x)$ on $[0,A]$ and $Y$ with pdf $g_Y(y)$ on $[0,B]$. Let's denote $Z=X+Y$. What should be the distribution of $X$, given $Z$?

Many thanks!

Comment: Which definition of conditional distribution are you using?

Comment: What do you mean? I was thinking of defining h(X|Z=X+Y) and expressing it somehow in terms of f(.) and g(.)

Comment: Equivalently: what have you been taught to check that a conditional density is indeed correct? (Unrelated: please use `@user` to comment to `user`.)

Comment: no, i need to use this conditional density in order to proof something else, but I don't know how to derive it

Comment: **Use @ please.**

Comment: oh, sorry, I am totally new here @Did

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Comment: @Did - Yes, thank you

Comment: Then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In full generality, the conditional distribution of a random variable $X$ conditionally on a random variable $Z$ is a family $(\nu_z)_z$ of distributions such that $\mathbb E(\varphi(X)\mid Z)=A_\varphi(Z)$ for every bounded measurable function $\varphi$, where
$$
A_\varphi(z)=\int\varphi(x)\mathrm d\nu_z(x).
$$
This means that, for every bounded measurable function $\psi$, 
$$
\mathbb E(\varphi(X)\psi(Z))=\mathbb E(A_\varphi(Z)\psi(Z)).
$$
In the present case, assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, one gets
$$
\mathbb E(\varphi(X)\psi(Z))=\iint\varphi(x)\psi(x+y)f(x)g(y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy,
$$
and the goal is to identify $\varphi\mapsto A_\varphi$ such that this coincides with
$$
\mathbb E(A_\varphi(Z)\psi(Z))=\iint A_\varphi(x+y)\psi(x+y)f(x)g(y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy,
$$
for every bounded measurable function $\psi$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Many thanks!I need to think about it.

Comment: I followed the explicit expression in the second answer and I have a short follow-up question to it. I am not sure how it works and who sees my comments so I post it here as well. I need to find conditions for which the ratio of the conditional probability to the prior is increasing in the random variable. In other words: $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\left(\frac{g(Z-X)}{\int_{Max(0,Z-B)}^{Min(Z,A)} f(X)g(Z-X)dX}\right) \geq 0$. I am not sure how to proceed with this weird bounds of integration. Any help will be very highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I like the way you ask a new question by appending a comment to each answer you received. As they say, if you have a new question, then post a new question.

Comment: Sorry, did not know how to do that, I am new here

Comment: Nonsense. You asked a question before, do it again.

Comment: I meant: I did not know I cannot communicate back (comment back) with the person who answered

Answer (score 6):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* and continuous, find the joint probability density function for $X$ and $Z$, i.e. $f_{X,Z}(x,z)$.

The probability density function of the conditional random variable then reads:
$$
    f_{X|Z}\left(x\mid z\right) = \frac{f_{X,Z}(x,z)}{f_Z(z)}
$$
where $f_Z(z)$ is the marginal pdf of $Z$, which is obtained as $f_Z(z) = \int_0^A f_{X,Z}(x,z) \mathrm{d}x$.

To find $f_{X,Z}(x,z)$ simply change measure in an expectation of a bounded function:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left(h(X,Z)\right) = \int_0^A \int_0^B h(x,x+y) f_X(x) g_Y(y) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = \int_0^A \int_0^{A+B} h(x,z) f_{X,Z}(x,z) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}z
$$
to find
$$
    f_{X,Z}(x,z) = f_X(x) g_Y(z-x) [ 0<x<A, x<z<B+x ]
$$
and therefore:
$$
    f_Z(z) = \int_{\max(0,z-B)}^{\min(z,A)} f_X(x) g_Y(z-x) \mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Thank you vey much!Isn't Min(Z,A)=A?

Comment: Appearance of $\min(z,A)$ simply says that when $z<A$, $f_Z(z)$ is zero.

Comment: oh, I see, thanks. And Max(0,z-B)? Z-B is in [-B,A]

Comment: I have a short follow-up question: I need to find conditions for which the ratio of the conditional probability to the prior is increasing in the random variable. In other words: $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\left(\frac{g(Z-X)}{\int_{Max(0,Z-B)}^{Min(Z,A)} f(X)g(Z-X)dX}\right) \geq 0$. I am not sure how to proceed with this weird bounds of integration. Any help will be very highly appreciated.